# Shall the sql delete the data in the transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

So I have that logic. How that will work

```
@Transactional
    public Rel unfollowUser() {
     myRepository.deleteAllFromTable1();
     myRepository.getAllFromTable1(); return new Rel();}
```

The question is: shall the second transaction get the data from the table? or shall the delete be commited before it? Does it depend on something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the [`FlushMode` of the `Session` to `ALWAYS` should do the trick](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#flushing-always).

Comment: this will flush the database queries one by one inside the transaction? or all at once? still cant get it

Comment: it flushes all the changes before each query

Comment: so get all from table will be empty

Comment: is there a possibility that after the delete getAllFromTable1 returns the records? even that we tried to delete them on the previous line?

Comment: and also where we can declare that Flushmode of the Session